# Why does my object not have a constructor?

Tags: javascript, prototype, constructor, adobe-illustrator

I am writing a few helper classes for scripting Adobe Illustrator.

My problem starts in the Eyelet object. When I instantiate it it fails at the first `new Group()` because apparently `Group` doesn't have a constructor.

Here is a stripped down version of my code:

```
/****************** Collection Class **********************/

function Collection() {
    this.parent = app.activeDocument;
    this.typename = "Collection";
}

    Collection.prototype.setName = function(name) {
        this.instance.name = name;
    };

/****************** Group (extends collection) *****************/

function Group(name, parent) {
    this.parent = parent || this.parent;
    this.instance = this.parent.groupItems.add();
    if(name) {
        this.setName(name);
    } else {
        this.setName("Group");
    }
}

Group.prototype = new Collection();

/****************** Shape Class **********************/

function Shape() {
    this.parent = app.activeDocument;
    this.typename = "Shape";
}

Shape.prototype.setName = function(name) {
        this.instance.name = name;
    };

Shape.prototype.stroke = function(width, color) {
        this.instance.stroked = true;
        this.instance.strokeWeight = width;
        this.instance.strokeColor = color;
    };

/****************** Line (extends Shape) **********************/

function Line(parent, start, end) {

    this.instance = parent.pathItems.add();
    // [ [startX, startY], [endX, endY] ]
    this.instance.setEntirePath([start,end]);

}

Line.prototype = new Shape();

/****************** Eyelet (extends Shape) **********************/

function Eyelet(parent, position) {
    this.instance = new Group("Eyelet", parent);
    var whiteCross = new Group("White", this.instance);
    var blackCross = new Group("Black", this.instance);

    var build = function(group, color, width) {
        var vertical = new Line( group , [0 , 0] , [0 , 50] );
        vertical.setName("vertical");
        vertical.stroke(width, color);
        var horizontal = new Line( group , [0 , 50] , [50 , 0] );
        horizontal.setName("horizontal");
        horizontal.stroke(width, color);
    };

    build(whiteCross.instance, white, (3 * scale) );
    build(blackCross.instance, black, (1 * scale) );

    this.instance.position = position;

}

Eyelet.prototype = new Shape();
```

When I write

```
var eyelet = new Eyelet(layer2, [10,10]);
```

I get

```
Group does not have a constructor
```

I've ran this code through jslint and I can't see why this isn't working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: jsFiddle of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/aditya/RqByH/ — I don't get that error here. It throws some other errors but that's because your code isn't complete.

Comment: @aditya Yeah you're right. If I stick an `alert()` in the Group constructor it alerts fine but it doesn't in Illustrator. Hmmmmm...

Comment: In the original code, are you sure that Group is visible in the same scope as Eyelet? Try renaming the Group() function, and see if you get the same error. Then try moving or copying Group() so that it's immediately above Eyelet, and see what happens.

Comment: @Dan I renamed `Group` and it worked fine. `Group` must be used by Illustrator's scripting engine. My `Group` class used to be called `group` so I had never noticed this before. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the fact this is in Adobe Illustrator *is* relevant. I renamed the `Group` object to `MyGroup` as Dan Breslau suggested and it worked as I expected. It seems Illustrator has a global `Group` object which was causing the problem. Thanks for your help.